How to verify offchain signed message inside onchain program
I want to implement verfying signature same as ethereum in solana
ethereum guide (https://solidity-by-example.org/signature/)

You cannot call the ED25519 program onchain because it would be too expensive,
to answer. You will need to include another top-level ix as per Jon's answer
Check out another answer from Jon on the need to call the program as a pre-compile, https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/16605/1708

I working over an app in which users will signed a message offchain using phantom wallet , then I want to verify that signature on chain.Making sure that users private key would be secure through out mechansim that's the reason I am not working with secp256k1.edsaSign(). So any guide how can I achieve verification think?

https://docs.rs/miraland-sdk/latest/solana_sdk/secp256k1_instruction/index.html
